# Eval/Bind TimeOfDay property without milliseconds?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, eval

I'm trying to format the following:

```
<%# Bind("TimeOfDay","{0:HH:mm:ss}") %>


<%# Eval("TimeOfDay","{0:HH:mm:ss}") %>

<%# Bind("TimeOfDay","{0:HH:mm:ss tt}") %>
```

But using either of those returns time as following:

> 08:33:08.1430000

How can I only get the `08:33:08` part?

Thanks,
EtonB.

Comment: is `TimeOfDay` typed as `DateTime` to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((DateTime)Eval("TimeOfDay")).ToString("HH:mm:ss")` ?